# Is there a benefit to getting Windows 8 PRO vs. HOME when using VMWARE virtualization?

Tags: windows-8, vmware

I'm getting a new PC (16GB RAM, i5 processor) and wondering if I need Windows 8 PRO or if HOME is sufficient.

The only feature I'd use (I think) is maybe the Windows 8 Virtualization. I read a bit about it but it's unclear whether VMWARE takes advantage of it or not.

Comment: `Windows 8 Professional` has `Hyper-V` which indeed does use some of specific CPU features for virtualization. These features are required to even install `Hyper-V`, I strongly suggest if you wish to use `Hyper-V` built into Windows 8, you make sure your new CPU will have the required features. VMWare does not require them. The differences between `Windows 8` and `Windows 8 Professional` are well documented so I won't repeat those differences.

Comment: @Ramhound I would prefer Vmware over Hyper-V. Hyper-V has a terrible guest performance for me. The GUI of the guest is sluggish while vmware is much, much faster.

Comment: @magicandre1981 There are lots of features that make Hyper-V your personal experience taken out of it, whats better a free virtual machine application built into the operating that allows you to boot to the virtual machine itself, or a third-party application costing $200.  I assume the author must be able to create virtual machines also.

Comment: @all I currently use (and have a lot of VHDs for) Vmware, so I'm planning to stick with that if possible.

Does Hyper-V (free version) allow you to CREATE aditional VM's or do I need to buy something from MS for that?

Comment: @Ramhound the VMware player is free and also let you create new VMs. But it lacks features like snapshots. Running Hyper-V and Vmware side by side doesn't work. The 2 hypervisor can't run the same time.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - I am well aware you cannot run VMWare with Hyper-V installed